# Delegate, method calls with multiple subscribers

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, delegates

I'm learning C and C#, and my question is for C#. What happens if I pass a delegate as a parameter for a method, but the delegate has multiple subscribers?
[image]
  [image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the code:

```
    evenPredicate += someMethod;
    evenPredicate += anotherMethod;
    List<int> evenNumbers = FilterArray(numbers, evenPredicate);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of a delegate with multiple subscribers is the return value of the **last** item; you can casually (not formally) verify this:

```
Func<int> x = () => { Console.WriteLine("1"); return 1; };
x += () => { Console.WriteLine("2"); return 2; };
int y = x(); // 2
```

Note that all the subscribers were *invoked*, though. Simply: most of the results were discarded. If an implementation so wishes, they can get the individual subscribers using `GetInvocationList()`, to process the results individually, but usually in this type of scenario it is reasonable to assume a predicate acts as though it is a single subscriber.

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice to use return value from multicast delegate. Most possible that you will get value, returned from last attached delegate instance.

When you assign delegate instance to delegate with '=' as in you example, you just remove all attached instanced and add new. Use '+=' operatop to attach another one.